¿Modificar el texto del output que arroja Jupyter Notebook?
Estoy iniciando en la programación. Estoy extrayendo valores numéricos de dataframe (con Pandas) y los utilizo para realizar operaciones básicas. Al imprimir la variable que utilizo como resultado, me arroja el valor que necesito, pero con texto adicional, como el titulo de la fila de donde lo extraje, titulo de la columna y el tipo de dato (float64). Aunque solo es estético, no me permite editar el “print()” para poder presentar el resultado de manera formal con unidades y demás. Subo una imagen como ejemplo...

En el ejemplo de salida, el 324.45 es el único valor que me gustaría obtener y no el resto.
Gracias

Creo que eso es una serie. Deberías extraer el valor individual de la serie y operar con él. De esa forma no estaría adornado ya que sería un valor de un tipo integrado de Python. Prueba con serie[0]
